# Example of a sequence that is Cauchy in a stronger norm and convergent in a weaker norm, but not convergent in the stronger norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

A norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ on a normed vector space is called stronger than $\|\cdot\|_2$ when $\|x\|_2\leq M\|x\|_1$ for some $M>0$ and all $x$. It is a standard trick (e.g. in proving completeness) to find the limit in a weaker sense first, and then prove that it is a stronger limit, e.g. [Cauchy in Norm and Weakly converge Implies Norm convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163858/152568). But it always uses some extra information beyond one convergence being weaker than the other. Examples in [Cauchy sequence converge for one metric while not converging for another?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3175604/152568) are not for norm metrics, hence the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No ZFC is needed since the completness of any of the norms    is not required in OP. Therefore an example can be constructed explicitly.

Let $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N})$ denote the space of sequences with finitely many nonzero terms with the standard basis $\{\delta_n\}_{n=1}^\infty.$ Consider two norms $$\|x\|_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|,\quad\|x\|_2=\|x\|_1+\left |x_1-\sum_{n=2}^\infty nx_n \right |$$ Then $\|\cdot \|_1\le \|\cdot \|_2.$ The sequence $v_k=\delta_1-{1\over k}\delta_k$ tends to $\delta_1$ with respect to $\|\cdot \|_1$ norm. On the other hand $\|v_k-\delta_1\|_2={1\over k}+1$ for $k\ge 2.$ Hence the sequence $v_k$ is not convergent to $\delta_1$ with respect to $\|\cdot \|_2$ norm. However for $k,l\ge 2$ and $k\neq l$ we have
$$\|v_k-v_l\|_2=\left \|{1\over l}\delta_l-{1\over k}\delta_k\right \|_2={1\over l}+{1\over k}$$ therefore $v_k$ satisfies the Cauchy condition with respect to $\|\cdot \|_2.$ The sequence $v_k$ is not convergent with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$ as the only possible limit would be equal $\delta_1.$

What follows is based on a beautiful idea of @SeverinSchraven, who kindly agreed to include his results into the  answer and took care of the re-edition.

**Added:** The convergence with respect to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is a bit difficult to grasp and one might wonder what the completion looks like.

The example shows that this norm keeps track of some mass that "escapes to infinity". It is a bit hard to imagine how this exactly works, thus we change the norm to something that we are a more familiar with at the expense of making the underlying space more complicated. Namely, consider the following map

$$ i: \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \ell^1(\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty\}), (x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto ((x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, x_1 - \sum_{n=2}^\infty n x_n). $$

The first coordinate keeps track of $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$ and the second coordinate takes care of the mass wandering off to infinity. We define
$$ \Vert ((x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, x_\infty)\Vert_{\ell^1} = \Vert (x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \Vert_1 + \vert x_\infty \vert, $$
which is just the usual $\ell^1$ norm. One readily checks that $i: (\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}), \Vert \cdot \Vert_1) \rightarrow (\ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}, \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\ell^1})$ is an isometry. Thus, $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N})$ is isomorphic to $i(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}))$ as a normed space. Hence, if we want to classify the completion of $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N})$ (up to isomorphism), then it is enough to find the completion of $i(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}))$.

We are in much better shape now as $(\ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}), \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\ell^1})$ is a Banach space! Thus, the completion of $i(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}))$ is (isomorphic to) the closure of $i(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}))$ in $(\ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}), \Vert \cdot \Vert_{\ell^1})$.

We claim that the closure of $i(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}))$ in $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\})$ is just $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\})$ itself. For this it is enough to show that $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}) \subseteq \overline{i(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}))}$ as the former is dense in $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\})$ (just truncate). Let's fix any $((x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N,0, 0, 0, \dots), x_\infty)\in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\})$ and set $x=(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N,0, 0, 0, \dots)$, then we can pick for $M>N$

\begin{align*}
v_M &= i(x +\frac{1}{M}(-x_\infty+x_1- \sum_{n=2}^N n x_n) \delta_M) \\
&= (x+ \frac{1}{M}(-x_\infty+x_1- \sum_{n=2}^N n x_n) \delta_M, x_\infty).
\end{align*}

Now we need to show that $(v_M)_{M\geq N+1}$ converges to $(x, x_\infty)$ in $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\})$. We have

\begin{align*}
\Vert v_M - (x, x_\infty) \Vert_{\ell^1}
= \frac{1}{M}\left\vert -x_\infty+x_1- \sum_{n=2}^N n x_n\right\vert
\end{align*}

which clearly tends to zero.

Note that we actually have $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}) \cong \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ (as Banach spaces) via the isomorphism
$$ \ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}) \rightarrow \ell^1(\mathbb{N}), ((x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, x_\infty) \mapsto (x_\infty, x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots). $$

Comment: Thank you, very interesting. What will be the completion of $\mathcal{F}$ in $\|\cdot\|_2$, or more specifically, what sort of limit does this sequence have there? It seems unlikely that the limit is a sequence, some kind of Banach limit?

Comment: The completion will be a subspace of $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ because $\|x\|_2\ge \|x\|_1.$ On the other hand the completion contains all sequences such that $\sum n|x_n|<\infty, $ as $\|x\|_2\le 2\sum n|x_n|.$ I have no idea if there is a transparent description of this completion.

Comment: But if it is a subspace of $\ell^1$ the $\|\cdot \|_2$ limit there would have to be the limit in $\|\cdot \|_1$ as well, which can only be $\delta_1$. I thought the only way this can work is if the $\|\cdot \|_2$ completion has elements outside of $\ell^1$, and the limit is one of them. What am I missing?

Comment: You are right. The completion cannot be contained in $\ell^1.$ I will have to think it over, as I am getting lost when it comes to abstract stuff. Formally the completion is made of equivalence classes of the Cauchy sequences if I remember well.

Comment: I think we can embed $(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}, \Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$ into $(\ell^1(\mathbb{N}), \Vert \cdot \Vert_1)$ via the map $$ i:  (\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}, \Vert \cdot \Vert_2) \rightarrow (\ell^1(\mathbb{N}), \Vert \cdot \Vert_1), (x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto (x_1-\sum_{n=2}^\infty n x_n, x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots).$$ Thus, we need to find the completion of a certain subspace of $\ell^1$ where the first coordinate tracks something like "the mass transported to infinity". Under the embedding the sequence would converge to $(2, 1, 0, 0, 0, \dots)$.

Comment: Maybe it would be more transparent to use $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\})$ and write $$ i: \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \ell^1(\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}), (x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto ((x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, x_1-\sum_{n=2}^\infty n x_n). $$ Then $i(v_n)=(\delta_1-\frac{1}{k} \delta_k, 2)$ converges to $(\delta_1, 2) \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\})$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks! Very clever idea for describing the completion.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Very nice. I wish this could be added to the answer, I think it helpfully illuminates what goes on in this example. I vaguely thought it might be the direct sum of a subspace of $\ell^1$ with something that picks out asymptotics at infinity. Originally, I had the same intuition as Ryszard, that the stronger completion should sit inside the weaker completion, as usually happens with Lebesgue and Sobolev spaces, and I couldn't get past that mental block. But I guess that happens exactly because stronger Cauchy and weaker convergence implies stronger convergence in those cases.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc In fact, the completion should be isomorphic to $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{ \infty\})$ as we can approximate every sequence $((x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, C) \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\})$ by the sequence $i((x_1, \dots, x_N, \frac{1}{N+1} (x_1-C-\sum_{n=2}^N n x_n), 0, 0, 0, \dots))$. Thus, your initial guess was correct that the completion is indeed isomorphic to $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ :) I really like your counterexample! This would make a great exercise for a functional analysis class.

Comment: @Conifold Surely, I'd be happy if this would be added to this answer.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks! Could you please add the explanation into my answer by re-editing it ? I will give all the credit to you. I do not want to screw up your idea, especially that at the moment I am watching the tennis tournament in Cincinnati.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I have added some details to your answer. Please feel free to edit/delete whatever you like.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks a lot! It's perfect. I have added a note that the  re-edition and all the additional stuff is entirely yours.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks, that's very kind of you.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I think the last part can be simplified. It suffices to show that $i(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}))$ is dense in $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\})$ instead of $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}).$ In this way we avoid the convergence issues as the sums are finite. If you agree with that, could you please re-edit your part accordingly ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I absolutely agree. In fact that was the thing I did when I solved it on paper and then realized that it is actually dense in the whole space, which confused me and I spelled out the whole thing. I'll change it once I have time (probably in 10h or so). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I've added it according to your suggestion. If you wish me to make other changes, just let me know.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks,! Now it looks cool. I have dared to put the closure symbol over $i(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N})).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks, typing on my phone makes it impossible to create anything without typos.

Answer (score 5):

Using a Hamel basis of an infinite dimensional Banach space $(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ one finds a discontinuous linear functional $f$. We define a strictly stronger norm $\|x\|_1=\|x\|_2+|f(x)|$. The open mapping theorem implies that $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is not complete but every $\|\cdot\|_1$-Cauchy-sequence is also $\|\cdot\|_2$-Cauchy and hence $\|\cdot\|_2$-convergent.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that this is some kind of pathology. Is it consistent with ZF that this does not happen, i.e. there are no "explicit" examples that do not use the axiom of choice?